# Как использовать jquery-функции в onclick?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нашла готовый код прокрутки страницы вверх, но он не работает так, как ожидается:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
<a href="javascript://" onclick="$('body').scrollTo({top:0, left:0}, 1500);return   false;" title="Вверх"> Вверх </a> 
</body>
```

Можно ли использовать jquery-функции в onclick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function upBtn(){
   $('html,body').stop(true).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Ваш вариант сработал! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Оберните всё в функцию

```
function to_top(){

$('body').scrollTo({top:0, left:0}, 1500);
return   false;

}
```

И вызывайте

```
<a  onclick="to_top()" title="Вверх">
```

Comment: Не получилось. Добавила в <head> <script> 
1) function to_top(){...};
2) в обертке $(document).ready(function() {
function to_top(){...}});
Не работают оба варианта.